# Why is uiactivity indicator not being shown in nav bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactivityviewcontroller

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *activityView = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 14, 14)];
[activityView sizeToFit];
[activityView setAutoresizingMask:(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin)];

activityView.hidesWhenStopped = NO;

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:activityView];

[activityView startAnimating];
```

What is the reason the uiactivity indicator is not being shown in the top right corner? Nothing is displayed in the top right nav bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you not assign the color of Activity Indicator 
assign the color then i will show in navigation bar

```
activityView.color = [UIColor blackColor];
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the type of activity indicator...try this:

```
UIActivityIndicatorView * activityView = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];
activityView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 14, 14);
[activityView sizeToFit];
[activityView setAutoresizingMask:(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin)];

activityView.hidesWhenStopped = NO;

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:activityView];

[activityView startAnimating];
```